# How to speak fluent in southern accent?

Tags: american-accent, accent

I want to speak like George W Bush's accent and like cowboys.

Example:

> Y`all and Howdy?

I would die for this accent. I sincerely love this accent over cockney one.

Comment: I don't see a relevant specific question about the accent, can you please edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: You would surely die to have that accent. You do sincerely love it.

Comment: You might find this blog entry helpful: [Tawkin' Suthern: How to Speak with a Southern Accent](http://asiteaboutnothing.net/w_southern.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speak in a Southern (U.S.) accent, you have to immerse yourself in the language somehow. I assume you live in the UK if you're talking about a cockney accent, so it might be difficult for you to immerse yourself fully in the Southern dialect.

But here's a few ideas:

1. Watch American television shows and movies that take place in the South. Seems like you might like the Texan accent, so watch television that takes place there. Some movies and shows: Driving Ms. Daisy, Fried Green Tomatoes, W, The Green Mile, The Dukes of Hazard
2. Listen to country music. There is usually a lot of twangy accents happening in those songs. Find a musician you like and listen closely the delivery of their lyrics.
3. Keep a little notebook of all the phrases you like. Watch how actors and musicians recite those lines. Practice in the mirror.
4. Find an American and ask them to critique your accent. They usually can tell you if you're doing it well or not.

In no time, you'll be impressing colleagues and dates with your bona fide cowboy / Southern accent! But be careful -- some people don't like it because they think you're mocking them.

Comment: You realize that the "US southern" accent in a lot of movies and TV shows is often a caricature created by an actor, right?  Often that rendition isn't accurate at all.

Comment: Good point, but I think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: I'm from Boston, and the majority of actors who attempt the accent do a terrible job at it. So I don't think it's something confined to the South.